# Deploy Spring Boot app from bitbucket pipeline to azure?

Tags: azure, spring-boot, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a standard spring boot application hosted on a Bitbucket repo which uses a bitbucket-pipeline.yml file to run a maven build

```
image: maven:3.3.3

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          - mvn clean install
```

From the Upload a custom Java web app to Azure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-java-custom-upload Azure documentation it states that this file is needed for my spring boot app

```
Springboot
In order to get a Springboot application running you need to upload your JAR or WAR file and add the following web.config file. The web.config file goes into the wwwroot folder. In the web.config adjust the arguments to point to your JAR file, in the following example the JAR file is located in the wwwroot folder as well.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"
        arguments="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dserver.port=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT% -jar &quot;%HOME%\site\wwwroot\my-web-project.jar&quot;">
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I've two questions. Where should I add this file to the existing project directory struture? And then what commands should be added to the pipeline file to do a FTP deploy?